# Avoid List copy between R and Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

Let's say I have a `List` with a few elements (< 20) but each of them is a vector (`IntegerVector`, `Numericvector` or `CharacterVector`) of several GB. I therefor want to avoid any copy.

To remove element from my `List`, I write the following Rcpp code :

```
void list_remove_element (List x, int i) {
  Rcout << "Size before : " << x.size() << endl;
  x.erase(i);
  Rcout << "Size after : " <<x.size() << endl;
}
```

Internaly, this code effectively erase the corresponding. Sadly after the return of this function no change appears in R :

```
> u = list(a=1:5, b=3:4, c=5:6)
> list_remove_elements (u, 1)
Size before : 3
Size after : 2
> str(u)
List of 3
 $ a: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
 $ b: int [1:2] 3 4
 $ c: int [1:2] 5 6
```

As far as I have understood, using a function to grow or shrink an Rcpp object results of a data copy from the original object into a new object. Is there any solution to avoid this?

EDIT :

I also tried to do the following :

```
void list_remove_elements (SEXP x) {
  SET_VECTOR_ELT(x, 1, R_NilValue);
}
```

It almost works since I get :

```
> str(u)
List of 3
 $ a: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
 $ b: NULL
 $ c: int [1:2] 5 6
```

But I still have the element 'b' and not sure this is the correct way to do ...

Comment: Not with SEXP types which are always contiguous vectors.  Now, a list of vectors does not copy its vectors. Only the top-level list is re-created.

Comment: See the _Writing R Extensions_ manual and its hints about memory profiling.  That is probably what you want.

Comment: Why not just using `u[2] <- NULL`?

Comment: Make that `u[[2]] <- NULL`.

Comment: The point is that I have a lot of other functions that directly modify the argument. I then do not use return value and I would like for this function the same behavior (for consistency purpose).
Let's say I have a my list `A`. I use my other functions like this :
`fct1(A); fct2(A) ; `
And I don't really want to do the following :
`fct1(A); A = fct2 (A) ;`
But maybe I misunderstand your answers ...

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new list with some elements from an existing list is not making copies of the content, i.e.

```
> data <- list( x = rnorm(1e6), y = rnorm(1e6), z = rnorm(1e6) ).   
> pryr::object_size(data)
24 MB
> data2 <- data[ c("x", "y") ]
> pryr::object_size(data2)
16 MB
```

But `data` and `data2` share their memory

```
> pryr::object_size(data, data2)
24 MB
```

The memory would only be copied if your make changes to say data2$x

```
> data2$x[1] <- 12
> pryr::object_size( data, data2 )
32 MB
```

In the original `list_remove_element` function you just have to return `x` this will be a new list:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List list_remove_element (List x, int i) {
  x.erase(i);
  return x ;
}


/*** R
  data <- list( x = rnorm(1e6), y = rnorm(1e6), z = rnorm(1e6) )
  data2 <- list_remove_element(data, 1)

  pryr::object_size(data)
  pryr::object_size(data2)
  pryr::object_size(data, data2)
*/
```

which gives:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('~/Desktop/test.cpp')
>   data <- list( x = rnorm(1e6), y = rnorm(1e6), z = rnorm(1e6) )
>   data2 <- list_remove_element(data, 1)
>   pryr::object_size(data)
24 MB
>   pryr::object_size(data2)
16 MB
>   pryr::object_size(data, data2)
24 MB
```

Comment: Nice answer!  Did not think that memory sharing would be preserved after a return from Rcpp.

Answer (score -1):

If you rename your parameter to 'List& x', then you should probably get the desired result.

Like below:

```
void list_remove_element (List& x, int i) {
  Rcout << "Size before : " << x.size() << endl;
  x.erase(i);
  Rcout << "Size after : " <<x.size() << endl;
}
```